# Example for meteor.js, universe-i18n and react-todos together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, internationalization

I to study the meteor for example https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react
And I'm trying to add multilingual support. 
I created file translated.

[image]

In the file `/imports/ui/App.jsx` I added code:

```
import i18n from 'meteor/universe:i18n';

i18n.setLocale('en-US');

const T = i18n.createComponent();

i18n.setLocale('en-US').then(function () {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

And in render method I added:

```
 . . . . 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Todo List ({this.props.incompleteCount})</h1>
          <T>hello </T>
          <T _locale='ru-RU'>hello </T>
          <T tagType='h1'>hello </T>
  . . . .
```

file `en-US.i18n.json`

```
{ "hello": "hello world!" }
```

But the text is not translated as good examples unfortunately I have not found.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the file be called en-US ie using a hyphen instead of using an underscore?

Comment: Ok, I was update, but it did not change anything.

Comment: There's an extra space after `hello` - this might be the cause.

Comment: Have you found the issue?

Comment: Did you get it to work? Do you have a repo you could share as an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to set a namespace.
Your JSON file should be something like:

```
{ 
    "messages" :{"hello": "hello world!" }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
<T>messages.hello</T>
```